# Accessing WiFi information from Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, namespaces, opennetcf

I am currently trying to extract WiFi information such as signal strength and MAC address from my windows phone 7.5 for an accurate location app I am working on. The OpenNETCF.Net framework has all the functionality I require (and is even described my MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446491.aspx) however I cannot seem to be able to import the namespace into my project using visual studio. It complains that the framework was not designed for windows phone projects. Is there any way around this? Or does there exist and equivalent framework which would work on WP7?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 is only distantly related to Windows Mobile & Windows CE (for which that library is for).

There are [a few how-tos for dealing with network information on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202867%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), although I don't believe that WiFi signal strength is made available to apps at this point in time.

It is worth noting that there is a [specific how-to for accessing location information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431803%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), where the operating system can use Wi-Fi signal information to help triangulate location, where GPS is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it is **impossible** on `Windows Phone` current version